# Is there a formula not to count persons name more than once when summing a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have written this formula that sums the total amount a person has occupied a bed for that month.

```
=IF(Z12="E",Y15,SUM(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(ExpectedFeesTbl[[Home Code]:[Home Code]],HomeCodePL1)),0,IF(ExpectedFeesTbl[Resident code]<>OFFSET(ExpectedFeesTbl[Resident code],1,0),ExpectedFeesTbl[OCCUPIED DAYS16],0))))
```

This works well if there is only one resident code for the month. But I am now finding is that if a resident extends there stay and it is put into the sheet as such, it will sum there days twice as there is the same resident code twice.

What I would like is to have is that if there is a duplicate, then ignore it.

Comment: please mock up some data and [edit] the post to include the problem and expected output in tabular form.  It will help us understand the problem better.

Comment: Hi, sorry i haven't edited it yet, not being rude. I think i found the problem in some other formula so checking that first

Answer (score 0):

+1 on Scott's comment.
But as far as I understand, you are trying to get sum of fee amounts per resident in a month. If this is the case, a pivot table can work for you as it will not repeat the residents and furthermore you can apply filters on pivot table level instead of inner formula.